# Renaming column values in Pandas in alphabetical order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data set with a column that contains personal names, totally there are 60 names by `value_counts()`. I don't want to show those names when I analyze the data, instead I want to rename them to *participant_1, ... ,participant_60*.

I also want to rename the values in alphabetical order so that I will be able to find out who is *participant_1* later.

I started with create a list of new names:

```
newnames = [f"participant_{i}" for i in range(1,61)]
```

Then I try to use the function `df.replace`.

```
df.replace('names', 'newnames')
```

However, I don't know where to specify that I want *participant_1* replace the name that comes first in alphabetical order. Any suggestions or better solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need replace values in column in alphabetical order use [`Categorical.codes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.codes.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'names':list('bcdada'),

})

df['new'] = [f"participant_{i}" for i in pd.Categorical(df['names']).codes + 1]
#alternative solution
#df['new'] = [f"participant_{i}" for i in pd.CategoricalIndex(df['names']).codes + 1]

print (df)
  names            new
0     b  participant_2
1     c  participant_3
2     d  participant_4
3     a  participant_1
4     d  participant_4
5     a  participant_1
```

Comment: thank you, however,  I want to replace values inside columns. The real data contains 10 thousand observations in column. 60 is the value counts.

Comment: @Ping - Can you test `df['new'] = [f"participant_{i}" for i in pd.CategoricalIndex(df['names']).codes]` ?

Comment: @jezrael, thank you so much, that works! the categoricalindex starts from 0, is it possible to let it starts from 1?

Comment: @Ping - Edited answer, check it.

Answer (score 0):

use `rename`

```
df.rename({'old_column_name':'new_column_nmae',......},axis=1,inplace=1)
```

You can generate the mapping using a dict comprehension like this -

```
mapper = {k: v for (k,v) in zip(sorted(df.columns), newnames)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to replace column values not column names.

Create a `dict` with old_names and new_names then You can use `df.replace`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['names'] = ['sam','dean','jack','chris','mark']

x = ["participant_{}".format(i+1) for i in range(len(df))]

rep_dict = {k:v for k,v in zip(df['names'].sort_values(), x)}

print(df.replace(rep_dict))
```

Output:

```
        names
0  participant_5
1  participant_2
2  participant_3
3  participant_1
4  participant_4
```